# Clicking checkboxes with Selenium WebDriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having trouble getting some checkboxes to be clicked. the usual XPath does not work, and there is no ID. I have attached the HTML code.

[image: HTML code]

Answer (score 1):

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("custom-control-label")).click();
```

Try above line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#contactAuth")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='contactAuth']")).click();
  ```

Ideally, to `click()` on the element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.birtviewer_clickable[name='exportReport']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='birtviewer_clickable']"))).click();
  ```